# MySQL When to use quotation after SELECT AS

Tags: mysql

After reviewing the use of SELECT in mysql, I found after as, sometimes without single quotation and sometimes has.
For example:

```
SELECT * AS DAY
```

compare to:

```
SELECT * AS 'Cancellation Rate'
```

So when to use single quotation after SELECT AS?

Comment: You cannot alias `*`, and you never use single quotation marks for aliases; you use `\`` or `"`.

Comment: Quotes are necessary on aliases with spaces or aliases that are the same as keywords.

Answer (score 1):

for composite name  eg: `Cancellation Rate`.. use backtics   not quotes

```
 select my_col_name as `Cancellation Rate`
 from my_table
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper syntax would be something like:

```
SELECT column_name AS colname FROM table_name
```

As mentioned in the comment, you cannot not alias a 'select all', which is what `*` represents. It selects ALL columns from your table.

You can also alias a table's name, like:

```
SELECT * FROM employees e WHERE column_name = 1;
```

When you alias a table's name, it can be easier to read in larger and more complex queries such as Joins.

You can get a better idea of all the possibilities by exploring this page https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html, plenty of fairly easy to follow examples.